# Windows Server 2012r2 black screen after bootup logo

Tags: windows-server-2012, boot, windows-server-2012-r2

We had a recent power outtage and our VM hosts went down, today I see that the SQL VM which is running Server 2012r2 boots up, we see the Windows logo and then a black screen. I am unable to ctrl+alt+del and I have tried letting it sit for countless hours.

I've tried going through the repair options off the bootup CD and I've ran startrep.exe as well and it did not identify any issues.

I have also tried booting into safe mode but am greeted with the same black screen and unresponsive operating system.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 3):

Something borked your `winlogon.exe`, probably a corrupt registry based on your details. Try boot to a last known good configuration. If that doesn't work, time to break out the backup and restore procedures.